# Find total count of rows in webtable using xpath in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the count of total row from table using below code but it's not working.

```
public IWebElement DocTable => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCaseList_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr"));

int RowCount = DocTable.Count();
```

Below is the error I am getting:

> Error CS1061  'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [`FindElement()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElement.htm) finds the first [IWebElement](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement.htm) using the given method. Where as [Count](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-count-the-total-number-of-elements-in-the-list/) is a *List* property.

So to get a count of all the `<tr>` elements you need to create a *List* using [`FindElements()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElements.htm) as follows:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> DocTable => driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCaseList_DXMainTable']/tbody//tr"));
int RowCount = DocTable.Count;
```

Or

```
public IList<IWebElement> DocTable => driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCaseList_DXMainTable']/tbody//tr"));
int RowCount = DocTable.Count;
```

As an alternative,

```
int RowCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCaseList_DXMainTable']/tbody//tr")).Count;
```

**Note**: `Count` is not a method but a property.

Comment: i am still getting the error "Can not implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>

Comment: @Gopal Updated the second option with list, should work now, How about the first option? let me know the status.

Comment: still no success by using both options. now getting error for code "DocTable.Count " 'A field initializer can not reference to the non static field'

Comment: @Gopal Can you remove the _keyword_ **public** and retest and let me know the status?

Comment: @Gopal Well there were more changes with in the code. Can you please take the new lines of code and retest once again? With the current lines of code you shouldn't see the previous error.

Answer (score 0):

`FindElement` returns a single `IWebElement`, the first row in the table in that case. Use `FindElements` to get a list of the `<tr>` elements

```
public List<IWebElement> DocTable => driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCaseList_DXMainTable']/tbody/tr"));
```